# UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  Failed to resolve
>   attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x141
>   "res/color/abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml" a=2 r=0x7f0d0089}
>                                                                                    at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7071)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.(LinearLayout.java:1911)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1816)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1815)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:966)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)

I checked the others people of the same exception. But none of the solution works for me.

I already set the values-v21/styles.xml as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

But when i run on the devices. it crash like above. I think i am using the correct theme. I also set in the Androidmanifest.xml to use that AppTheme for application and activity. Still not works.

My sample code is working with the above theme. But the sample code has only one project. But porting to my job projects, which have several library and a bit complex structure, then it occurred for trying to use any appcompat v7 components. If not use, then its good. If use, then crash.

There are so many project libraries, and several gradles.

I add one of the project gradle that are trying to use the appcompt v7 components.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':xxxxLibrary')
    compile project(':xxxx2Library')
    compile project(':xxxxx3Library')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Any suggestion please?

By the way i can't update my target sdk version to latest. Due to runtime permission. And our ndk libraries have relocation issue that i have no permission to solve. So currently targetsdk is 21.

Three layouts file.
 1.  entry_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/entry_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/entry_view_pager_layout" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer-->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/entry_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

2. entry_view_pager_layout.xml

   ```
   <include layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>
   ```
3. app_toolbar.xml

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/app_toolbar_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Finally i delete other view pager and tab layout, only keep the toolbar to track the issue.

Comment: Hi, Could you add build.gradle with libraries what you use?

Comment: I add one of the gradle file.

Comment: @rodent_la show your xml layout please. (that you set via `setContentView()` in your activity)

Comment: updated, thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: @rodent_la I'm guessing that the problem is in `app_toolbar.xml` in `LinearLayout` or `AppbarLayout` ;) just see at inflate -> parseInclude -> parseInclude in stacktrace

Comment: @g4s8 thanks a lot for pointing out toolbar.  i found that the issue is because of android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"

i defined in demns.xml as <dimen name="actionBarSize">?attr/actionBarSize</dimen>

This sound error.

Comment: @rodent_la btw it's a good practice to use theme attribute for toolbar height in layout: `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`.

Comment: @g4s8, yes, i would like to use that. I want to put in dimen, so that any other one to follow that actionBarSize, if designer request to change, i want to change one place and the rest goes fine. So i decide to put in dimen.xml. But i didn't notice that i can't declare like that. There is no error during the build.